# Returning object containing references in Rust

Tags: rust

I have the following two types:

```
struct A {
    x: int
}

struct B<'a> {
    y: &'a A
}
```

I would like to create a function that creates an object of type A and an object of type B containing a reference to the object of type A, and returns the object of type B:

```
fn bar<'a>() -> B<'a> {
    let y = A { x: 3 };
    B { y: &y }
}
```

However I get the following compiler error:

```
main.rs:11:13: 11:14 error: `y` does not live long enough
main.rs:11     B { y: &y }
                       ^
main.rs:9:23: 12:2 note: reference must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 9:22...
main.rs:9 fn bar<'a>() -> B<'a> {
main.rs:10     let y = A { x: 3 };
main.rs:11     B { y: &y }
main.rs:12 }
main.rs:9:23: 12:2 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block at 9:22
main.rs:9 fn bar<'a>() -> B<'a> {
main.rs:10     let y = A { x: 3 };
main.rs:11     B { y: &y }
main.rs:12 }
error: aborting due to previous error
```

This error seems justified, by I can't find a way around the issue. Is there any way to specify that the lifetime of `y` should be at least `'a`, without changing the definition of `A` or `B`?

Comment: Can't `B` have the ownership of `A` ? Either as a direct field or as a `box` ?

Comment: `A` and `B` are defined in a library so I don't have control over their definition

Comment: In that case, you'll need to have a separated memory pool to handle your A's, like a static vector of boxes. Yet I'm not sure about how to implement this in a clean way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to specify that `y` lifetime should be at least `'a` because it is impossible: `y` is a local variable and it just *cannot* live longer than the stack frame it is created in.

In general, if you find a need to do such thing, it is very likely that you in fact do want `B` to own `A`:

```
struct B { y: A }
```

In this case the code becomes trivial:

```
fn bar() -> B {
    let y = A { x: 3 }
    B { y: y }
}
```

---

You can look to this from another point. This is the signature of `bar()` you want:

```
fn bar<'b>() -> B<'b> { ... }
```

`'b` is a lifetime *parameter*, that is, it can be chosen arbitrarily by the caller of this function. But nothing prevents the caller to substitute, for example, `'static` for `'b`:

```
let x: B<'static> = bar();
```

However, this is only possible if `bar()` *always* return `B<'static>`, which is not what you want, it seems. In fact, the above signature is exactly equivalent to this one:

```
fn bar() -> B<'static> { ... }
```

Comment: I see, it makes more sense now. Thanks for the explanation!